# Threads not acting on global variable

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a huge multi-threaded code base. There are 100 threads. 99 threads have a function `do_thread_operations` associated with each of them. 100th thread has an operation `monitor_99threads` associated with it.

`do_thread_operations` have infinite loop, so they never stop. `monitor_99threads` keeps track of time. One minute after it was started, it has to close all 99 threads and return to the main thread.

Following is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

int *to_close_thread;

void * do_thread_operations(void * thread_data){
    int i = *(int *)thread_data;
    while (1){
       //do something
       if (to_close_thread[i]) break;
    }
}

void * monitor_99threads(void * data){ 
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
       i++;
       if(i > 60){
          for (int i = 0; i < 99; ++i){
              printf("Closing %d", i);
              to_close_thread[i] = 1;  
          }
       }
    }
}

int main(){
    to_close_thread = (int *)malloc(99 * sizeof(int));
    memset(to_close_thread, 0, 99*sizeof(int));
    pthread_t threads[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; ++i){
        int j = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, do_thread_operations, (void *)&j);
    }
    pthread_create(&threads[99], NULL, monitor_99threads, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

}
```

Problem is that although closing prints, the threads do not break out of their loops.

Comment: You're passing `j` to a thread, and then changing the value of `j` in `main`. You need an array `id[100]` and then pass `&id[i]` to the thread.

Comment: @user3386109 No. I am redeclaring it.

Comment: Perhaps a synchronisation issue. You cannot assume that your threads will read variable j in the order they are created.

Comment: @clarasoft-it, I understand this. But even then, the thread will stop sometime right? it never breaks.

Comment: @SonuMishra In theory, `j` goes out of scope at the end of the block, and therefore ceases to exist. Which means that the thread (theoretically) is trying to access something that doesn't exist (which is worse than just accessing something that had its value changed). In practice, the compiler allocates four bytes on the stack for `j`, and then reuses those four bytes for each new instance of `j`. To understand this better, you should compile with `-S` and look at the assembly code that the compiler generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the problems described by @P.P., there appears to be a synchronization problem with the referent of `to_close_thread`.  Since the elements are not `_Atomic` and they are accessed without protection of a mutex, semaphore, or other synchronization object, the `do_thread_operations()` threads may not ever see any writes performed by `control_99threads()`.

Note also, by the way, that it's a bit silly to pass a pointer to an offset from the base of `to_close_thread` as the thread argument, when you could instead just pass a pointer directly to the appropriate element.  Then you don't need any kind of auxiliary variable:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; ++i){
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, do_thread_operations,
                (void *) (to_close_thread + i));
    }
```

The `do_thread_operations` can just cast it back to an `int *` and dereference it directly (under protection of a mutex or other appropriate synchronization object).

Comment: "threads may not ever see any writes performed by control_99threads()". I understand that when both thread and monitor access the element simultaneously, thread may read 0, when monitor had written 1. But in the next iteration, the thread will read it as 1 and break. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SonuMishra, yes, you are wrong.  There are several ways to look at it.  One of them is that without any synchronization, there is no meaningful definition of whether a given write happens before or after a given read, so the worker threads may not see any write in bounded time.  A more physical way to look at it is that without synchronization, the write may be reflected only in one core's cache (or in some cases, only in a register), where it is invisible to threads scheduled on other cores, for an unbounded time.

Comment: Each thread accesses a unique element in `to_close_thread`. So, not sure why you suggest synchronization is necessary.
`that it's a bit silly to pass a pointer to an offset from the base of to_close_thread as the thread argument` - actually, `to_close_thread`
is only modified by *montior* and passing it to thread, as you suggest is not going to work since they are all 0. Even if you set it to `1` before passing it to the thread, that would introduce a data race as monitor might be writing before thread(s) could read it and and it would make thread exit cond true even before montior sets it!

Comment: @P.P. "Two expression  evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location" (C2011, 5.1.2.4/4).  "The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other.  Any such data race results in undefined behavior" (C2011, 5.1.2.4/25).  "Happens before" is a defined relationship that is not established in the O.P.'s code or yours, but would be established by synchronization.

Comment: @P.P. As for the thread arguments, I am not suggesting passing the *referents* of the pointers, I am suggesting passing the pointers themselves, as my code demonstrates.  The worker threads would dereference those pointers to check the pointed-to value.  This is absolutely equivalent to what the O.P.'s code does, but it gets rid of the temporary variable.

Comment: I don't deny "Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location". But the question is whether it happens in OP's code.

Comment: @P.P. the monitor thread writes to `to_close_thread[i]` for various `i`.  Each worker thread reads `to_close_thread[i]` for one of the same `i`s (once the correction you recommended, or the related one I recommended, is implemented).  That's how the monitor thread attempts to communicate with the workers, so it is central to the O.P.'s problem, and the actions involved conflict.

Comment: Ah, I see. I completely missed it! I suppose I'll leave my answer as-is since you have answered. Perhaps, OP should accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 99; ++i){
        int j = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, do_thread_operations, (void *)&j);
    }
```

You are passing the address of `j`, which has block scope and has auto storage duration. You should something like:

```
    int arr[100] = {0}; /* adjust the number or allocate using malloc as per needs */
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; ++i){
        arr[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, do_thread_operations, &arr[i]);
    }
```

Another problem is your monitor thread doesn't break after sending closing message. As it is, it's running in an infinite loop. You probably need a `break;` statement when (whatever) condition is met.